# Falha ao converter para representação interna

Tags: java, oracle, genexus

Boa tarde,

Estou trabalhando com **Genexus Ev3 Up1**. Tenho um Data Provider que faço busca de uma consulta e retorna um SDT com as informações, porem da erro no **TOMCAT** com a mensagem de:

> **java.sql.SQLException**: Falha ao converter para representação Interna.

No banco de dados a consulta é gerada normalmente, somente na aplicação da o erro.

Obrigado.

Comment: Arthur, Para melhor lhe indicar um caminho, acredito ser necessário mais informações: - Detalhe um pouco mais "busca de uma consulta"? - Qual tipo de objeto estás executando?
- Retorna um Sdt com as informações pra onde? De qualquer forma, está me parecendo um erro de banco de dados. Como verificaste que "No banco de dados a consulta é gerada normalmente"? A melhor maneira de se verificar a consulta gerada é abrindo o cosigo fonte do objeto em questão.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Sandro, depois de uma boa análise verifiquei o erro, era no banco mesmo, a consulta gerava normalmente, porem tinha dados agregados com a função LISTAGG do oracle que ao converter para o genexus dava o erro, consertei isso e o problema foi resolvido, obrigado pela atenção.